# I upgraded my ASP.net website to .net 4.5 and now gridview doesn't show data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I recently upgraded my ASP.net website to .net 4.5 and suddenly my gridView control no longer shows any data using this code.  Before the upgrade it would show just fine. 'database' is a custom class I made to connect to my SQL database and run queries against it.  It uses an OLEDB connection.

```
DataSet data;
int retValue = 0;

data = database.ExecuteSQLStatement("SELECT * FROM MyTable", ref retValue);                       
gridViewTables.DataSource = data;
gridViewTables.DataBind();
```

Here is the html:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewTables" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"      AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="gridViewTables_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="gridViewTables_RowEditing" 
        OnRowUpdating="gridViewTables_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleted="gridViewTables_RowDeleted" OnRowDeleting="gridViewTables_RowDeleting">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Does your dataset have any data in it?

Comment: Confirmed.  it does have data.